# Find all unique values that are sums of sub-arrays of an array of numbers... simple?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sup fellow geeks!

I'm trying to make an array that lists all the possible values of the sums of the elements of an array. I'm sure this must be quite easy but I'm up to 2 or 3 hours now and I'm getting frustrated, I think I'm almost there...

```
var frootVals = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var frootInc = frootVals
var fruitEnd = frootInc[frootInc.length-1]//begins at 5
var fruitAll = 15 // The total of all the numbers in the array. (this is actually 
 // calculated in another function, but lets just say I declared it as 15)

  for (e = frootVals.length-2 ;fruitEnd !== fruitAll;e--){ //so I want it to 
//finish when the final array entry is 15.
  for (p = 1;p < e; p++){
    var incEnd = frootInc[frootInc.length-p]
    frootInc.push(incEnd + frootVals[p]) //1st time round (5 + 1 = 6, 5 + 2 = 7,
//5 + 3 =8, 5 + 4 = 9) THEN start again with 9 now being incEnd so pushes 
//9+1 = 10 etc etc until the last digit is 15 and the whole loop stops...
    }
    }
```

EDIT - Basically the final result I'm after is frootInc to be be an array of the integers [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] - I'm sure I'll kick myself for giving up but I've only been learning a few weeks so this is all quite brain taxing.

Comment: Just for clarification, would your arrays always be sequential? For example, could you have an array that looks like `[1,2,5,7,10]`? Or, will it always be something like `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`. Also, will it always start with 0? Or, could you have an array that looks like `[2,3,4]`, which outputs `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` or would it output `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`?

Comment: Hi Jack. No, not always sequential but always starting with 0 - the end result of this is for a slider, so I need the array to link to checkboxes which attain to values and 0 being nothing selected. I hope that makes sense, sometimes my terminology can be misleading!

Comment: Cool! If you don't mind, one last question: Would an array like `[0,2,5,8]` output `[0,2,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]` or `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`.

Comment: Hey Jack, sorry for delay - [0,2,5,8] would need to output... [0,2,5,7,10,13,15] (so all of the possible values of addition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about your question a bit, I think the easiest solution would be with recursion when the condition that the final value added to the array is less than the sum of values.

Here's a JS Fiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgzwpky/

To break it down a bit (and so that you may confirm I have the question right :D), say we have the following array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 30]
```

The sum of the values are: `61`. So the expected output array would be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 45, 46, 47, 48, 55, 60, 61]
```

To further break it down, the looping logic would do something like this:

```
// Get final value to add to previous values
var val = [0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 30].pop();

// Add the final value - 30 - to all previous values (ignoring the zero)

.. loop here and push the values to our array ...

// For the first iteration, the updated array looks like:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 45]

// New values calculated from: 30 + 1, 30 + 2, 30 + 3, 30 + 10, 30 + 15
```

At this point, our max value of `61` is less than the final value of `45` So, we do it again!

```
var val = [0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 45].pop();

.. loop here and push the values to our array ...

// Second iteration, the updated array looks like:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 30, 31, 32, 33, 40, 45, 46, 47, 48, 55, 60, 61]

// New values are: 45 + 1, 45 + 2, 45 + 3, 45 + 10, 45 + 15
// Note that 45 + 30 would be greater than our sum of 61, so we break
```

If that's correct, here's a script that I wrote that populates such an array:

```
function getPopulatedArray(arr) {
    var max = arguments[1] || getSum(arr),
        current = arr.pop(),
        temp = [],
        i = 1,
        len = arr.length;

    // Populate temp array with values
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] + current) < max) {
            temp.push(arr[i] + current);
        } else {
            temp.push(max);
            break;
        }
    }
    arr.push(current);
    arr = arr.concat(temp);

    // Done? Or should we continue?
    if (arr[arr.length - 1] < max) {
        return getPopulatedArray(arr, max);
    } else {
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Again, the JS fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgzwpky/

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: ... just... wow. Many humble thanks - can't believe you went to all the effort of making a little box so I can test it out. I'm blown away that you'd go to so much trouble, even to go away, think about it, then come back to it! Really, really grateful Jack. There's no WAY I would have sussed that on my own. Thanks.

Researched and understand the pop method, the concat method and have also realised that if I spent more time going through my Definitive Guide I'd have more chance at being able to do things like this by myself!

Comment: Only thing I don't understand is this line:
var max = arguments[1] || getSum(arr)
Why is it an OR and what's arguments[1] - I couldn't find it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks @HenryDavidTHROW. The `||` operator is used to pass in the max value on recursive calls (otherwise, we'd recalculate the `sum` and get a different value each time). It could have been global, but it's nice to minimize those! `arguments` is an object in JS specific to a function. When a function is defined, you also define the parameters. However, in JS, it's not required to call your function with all of the arguments (or, you can pass additional arguments to your your function - or `varargs`).When you pass additional arguments, the question becomes: How do you access those?

Comment: That's where the `arguments` object comes into play! Here's an example: Say we have `function friends() { ... }` which takes a list of friends and does something with it - If you're popular, your call may look like: friends('jack', 'jim', 'john', ...n). You'd access each argument as `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]`, `arguments[2]` (In JavaScript, some objects are `array-like` - arguments is one!) Hope this helps! Here's an MDN article on arguments (with more info): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Ahhhhhh. It all makes perfect sense. It's like solving riddles every time!! I love programming! I'm 27 now and I wish I'd taken it up when I was younger, can only imagine some of the incredible stuff there'll be in the future. Thanks for your help Jack, sending good vibes.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to do something like this:

```
var frootVals = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < frootVals.length; i++){     // Iterate over the array twice
    for (var j = 0; j < frootVals.length; j++){ // To calculate all combinations
        result.push(frootVals[i] + frootVals[j]);
    }
}
```

Now, if you don't want duplicates, try this:

```
var frootVals = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < frootVals.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < frootVals.length; j++){
        var value = frootVals[i] + frootVals[j];
        if(result.indexOf(value) === -1){
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use `result = result.sort()` if you want to output a sorted result.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! This works to add the highest value of the array to the highest value, but it only returns numbers up to 10 - I'm looking for an algorithm that will add all the numbers together (ie, max up to 15)... this may be more complicated than I thought. I'm going to use this information you've been kind enough to add and try to work out the rest. Thanks Cerbrus.

Comment: How do you plan on getting `15`? Do you want to add all these numbers together 3 times?

Comment: No, all together. Ie. 1+2+3+4+5 = 15.

Comment: Oooh, that's going to be a little more problematic.

Comment: Ha, I think so. I'm still going for it though. There's some algorithm out there somewhere that I'm missing, I'm sure.